# Make cmake library avaialble to other library

Tags: cmake, stm32, header-files

I have a CMSIS library. It contains only header .h files with MCU register definitions. CMSIS is fetched and parsed with `FetchContent_Declare()` and a separated *Findcmsis.cmake*. The project directory looks similar to this:

```
+-- build
|       +-- ...
|       +-- cmsis-src
|       +-- ...
|
+-- sources
|         +-- file.c
|         +-- file.h
|         +-- CMakeLists.txt
|
+-- cmake
|       +-- Findcmsis.hal
|
+-- CMakeLists.txt
```

I would like to make it available to all other libraries linked in the main CMakeLists.txt. I understand I should use `INTERFACE` type since this is header based library, with no sources to be compiled.
However if I use `INTERFACE` type instead of `PUBLIC`, that library will be not available to other libraries in in `target_link_libraries()` command.

EDIT Adding cmake code used in the project

*Findcmsis.cmake*

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

set(cmsisSupportedModules
    stm32
)

set(stm32
    f0 f1 f2 f3 f4 f7 h7 g0 g4 l0 l4 l5 u5 wl wb
)

message(STATUS "Find Module: cmsis")

# STM32
set(stm32-families              f0      f1      f2      f3      f4      f7      g0      g4      h7      l0      l1      l4     )
set(stm32-repositories
    "null"  # f0
    "null"  # f1
    "null"  # f2
    "null"  # f3
    "null"  # f4
    "null"  # f7
    "null"  # g0
    https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/cmsis_device_g4  # g4
    "null"  # h7
    "null"  # l0
    "null"  # l1
    "null"  # l4
)

## STM32 G4
set(stm32.g4-cmsisVersion       v1.0.0  v1.1.0  v1.1.1  v1.2.0  v1.2.1)
set(stm32.g4-cmsisCoreVersion   5.4.0   5.4.0   5.4.0   5.6.0   5.6.0)


set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

foreach(component ${cmsis_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    string(REGEX MATCH "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)$" output ${component})

    set(mcuFamilyName ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
    set(mcuSubfamilyName ${CMAKE_MATCH_2})
    set(cmsisVersionRequired ${CMAKE_MATCH_3})

    if(mcuFamilyName IN_LIST cmsisSupportedModules)
        if(mcuSubfamilyName IN_LIST "${mcuFamilyName}-families")
            if(NOT ${cmsisVersionRequired} IN_LIST "${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}-cmsisVersion")
                message(FATAL_ERROR "Required CMSIS version not supported for this MCU family: ${cmsisVersionRequired}, ${mcuFamilyName}-${mcuSubfamilyName}")
            endif()
        else()
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Required CMSIS MCU subfamily not supported: ${mcuFamilyName}-${mcuSubfamilyName}")
        endif()
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Required CMSIS MCU family not supported: ${mcuFamilyName}")
    endif()
    
    # Fetch CMSIS Core from ARM
    list(FIND "${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}-cmsisVersion" ${cmsisVersionRequired} index)
    list(GET "${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}-cmsisCoreVersion" ${index} cmsisCoreVersion)
    
    # Skip fetching CMSIS Core if that version has been already fetched by other component
    if(NOT cmsis-${cmsisCoreVersion}_POPULATED)
        FetchContent_Declare(
            cmsis
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5.git
            GIT_TAG ${cmsisCoreVersion}
            GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
        )

        FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cmsis)

        if (NOT EXISTS "${cmsis_SOURCE_DIR}/CMSIS/Core/Include")
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot locate CMSIS source files after fetching repository")
        endif()
    endif()

    add_library(
        cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}
        INTERFACE
        IMPORTED
    )

    target_include_directories(
        cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}
        INTERFACE
        "${cmsis_SOURCE_DIR}/CMSIS/Core/Include"
    )

    list(APPEND include_directories "${cmsis-${cmsisCoreVersion}_SOURCE_DIR}/CMSIS/Core/Include")

    # Fetch processor specific CMSIS from vendor
    list(FIND "${mcuFamilyName}-families" ${mcuSubfamilyName} index)
    list(GET "${mcuFamilyName}-repositories" ${index} repository_url)

    FetchContent_Declare(
        cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}
        GIT_REPOSITORY ${repository_url}
        GIT_TAG ${cmsisVersionRequired}
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
    )

    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName})

    if (NOT EXISTS "${cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}_SOURCE_DIR}/Include")
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot locate CMSIS vendor provided source files after fetching repository")
    endif()

    target_include_directories(
        cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}
        INTERFACE
        "${cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}_SOURCE_DIR}/Include"
    )

    list(APPEND include_directories "${cmsis.${mcuFamilyName}.${mcuSubfamilyName}_SOURCE_DIR}/Include")
    
endforeach()

find_package_handle_standard_args(
    cmsis
    REQUIRED_VARS include_directories
    FOUND_VAR cmsis_FOUND
    HANDLE_COMPONENTS
)
```

*Findhal.cmake*

```
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

set(supportedFamilies
    stm32
)

# STM32
set(stm32-supportedSubfamilies
    g4
)

set(stm32-repositories
    https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32g4xx_hal_driver/ # g4
)
## G4
set(stm32.g4-halDrivers             adc comp cordic cortex crc cryp dac dma exti fdcan flash flash_ramfunc fmac gpio hrtim i2c i2s irda iwdg lptim nand nor opamp pcd pwr qspi rcc rng rtc sai smartcard smbus spi sram tim uart usart wwdg)
set(stm32.g4-halExtendedDrivers     adc crc cryp dac dma flash i2c opamp pcd pwr rcc rtc sai smartcard spi tim uart usart)
set(stm32.g4-halLowLevelDrivers     adc comp cordic crc crs dac dma exti fmac fmc gpio hrtim i2c lptim lpuart opamp pwr rcc rng rtc spi tim ucpd usart usb utils)
set(stm32.g4-supportedVersions      v1.0.0  v1.1.0  v1.1.1  v1.2.0  v1.2.0  v1.2.1)



set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

foreach(component ${hal_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    string(TOLOWER ${component} componentLowerCase)
    string(TOUPPER ${component} componentUpperCase)

    # Check HAL version if it's supported
    string(REGEX MATCH "^([a-zA-z0-9]+).([a-zA-z0-9]+)-([a-zA-z0-9.]+)$" output ${componentLowerCase})
    set(mcu_family_name_found ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
    set(mcu_subfamily_name_found ${CMAKE_MATCH_2})
    set(hal_version_required_found ${CMAKE_MATCH_3})
    
    if(mcu_family_name_found IN_LIST supportedFamilies)
        if(NOT mcu_subfamily_name_found IN_LIST "${mcu_family_name_found}-supportedSubfamilies")
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Requested subfamily for HAL component is not supported: ${componentLowerCase}")
        endif()

        if(NOT hal_version_required_found IN_LIST "${mcu_family_name_found}.${mcu_subfamily_name_found}-supportedVersions")
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Requested version for HAL component is not supported: ${componentLowerCase}")
        endif()

        set(mcu_family_name ${mcu_family_name_found})
        set(mcu_subfamily_name ${mcu_subfamily_name_found})
        set(hal_version_required ${hal_version_required_found})

        list(APPEND hal_modules_requested ${componentLowerCase})
        
        continue()
    endif()
    
    # At least one version shall be provided at the very beginning of the COMPONENTS list
    if(NOT mcu_family_name)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot process HAL components without setting MCU family and version first. Please add HAL version at the beginning of COMPONENTS list.")
    endif()

    # Check if component name matches HAL drivers list
    if(${componentLowerCase} IN_LIST "${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-halDrivers")
        list(APPEND ${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-${hal_version_required}-halDriversMatched ${component})
        continue()
    endif()

    # Check if component name matches HAL extended drivers list
    string(REGEX REPLACE "_ex$" "" componentLowerCase ${componentLowerCase})
    if(${componentLowerCase} IN_LIST "${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-halExtendedDrivers")
        list(APPEND ${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-${hal_version_required}-halExtendedDriversMatched ${component})
        continue()
    endif()

    # Check if component name matches HAL low level drivers list
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^ll_" "" componentLowerCase ${componentLowerCase})
    if(${componentLowerCase} IN_LIST "${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-halLowLevelDrivers")
        list(APPEND ${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-${hal_version_required}-halLowLevelDriversMatched ${component})
        continue()
    endif()

    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown HAL component: ${component}")
endforeach()

# Start processing requested componenets after verification
foreach(hal_module ${hal_modules_requested})
    message(DEBUG "Procesing module: ${hal_module}")

    string(REGEX MATCH "^([a-zA-z0-9]+).([a-zA-z0-9]+)-([a-zA-z0-9.]+)$" output ${hal_module})
    set(mcu_family_name ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
    set(mcu_subfamily_name ${CMAKE_MATCH_2})
    set(hal_version_required ${CMAKE_MATCH_3})

    # If empty, request automatically full list of available components
    if((NOT ${hal_module}-halDriversMatched) AND (NOT ${hal_module}-halExtendedDriversMatched) AND (NOT ${hal_module}-halLowLevelDriversMatched))
        set(${hal_module}-halDriversMatched ${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-halDrivers)
        set(${hal_module}-halExtendedDriversMatched ${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-halExtendedDrivers)
        set(${hal_module}-halLowLevelDriversMatched ${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}-halLowLevelDrivers)
    endif()

    # Fetch HAL library from vendor repository
    list(FIND ${mcu_subfamily_name} "${${mcu_family_name}-supportedSubfamilies}" index)
    list(GET "${mcu_family_name}-repositories" ${index} repository_url)

    # Skip fetching CMSIS Core if that version has been already fetched by other component
    if(NOT hal.${hal_module}_POPULATED)
        FetchContent_Declare(
            hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}
            GIT_REPOSITORY ${repository_url}
            GIT_TAG ${hal_version_required}
            GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
        )

        FetchContent_MakeAvailable(hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name})
    endif()

    if ( EXISTS "${hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}_SOURCE_DIR}/Inc/stm32${mcu_subfamily_name}xx_hal.h" )
        set(halIncludeDirectory "${hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}_SOURCE_DIR}/Inc")
    else ()
        message( FATAL_ERROR "HAL include directory has not been found!" )
    endif ()

    if ( EXISTS "${hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}_SOURCE_DIR}/Src/stm32${mcu_subfamily_name}xx_hal.c" )
        set(halSourceDirectory "${hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}_SOURCE_DIR}/Src")
    else ()
        message( FATAL_ERROR "HAL source directory has not been found!" )
    endif ()

    message(DEBUG "HAL drivers: ${${hal_module}-halDriversMatched}")
    message(DEBUG "HAL extended drivers: ${${hal_module}-halExtendedDriversMatched}")
    message(DEBUG "HAL low level drivers: ${${hal_module}-halLowLevelDriversMatched}")
    message(DEBUG "hal_SOURCE_DIR: ${hal.${hal_module}_SOURCE_DIR}")

    unset(halDriversMerged)
    list(APPEND halDriversMerged "${${hal_module}-halDriversMatched}")
    list(APPEND halDriversMerged "${${hal_module}-halExtendedDriversMatched}")
    list(APPEND halDriversMerged "${${hal_module}-halLowLevelDriversMatched}")

    foreach(component ${halDriversMerged})
        set(componentSourceFile "${halSourceDirectory}/stm32${mcu_subfamily_name}xx_hal_${component}.c")
        message(DEBUG "Component source file: ${componentSourceFile}")

        if (EXISTS "${componentSourceFile}")
            if( NOT (TARGET hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name} ) )
                add_library(
                    hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}
                    INTERFACE
                    IMPORTED
                )

                target_include_directories(
                    hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}
                    INTERFACE
                    "${halIncludeDirectory}"
                )

                target_sources(
                    hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}
                    INTERFACE
                    "${halSourceDirectory}/stm32${mcu_subfamily_name}xx_hal.c"
                )
            endif()

            add_library(
                hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}.${component}
                INTERFACE
                IMPORTED
            )

            target_link_libraries(
                hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}.${component}
                INTERFACE
                hal.stm32.g4
            )

            target_sources(
                hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}.${component}
                INTERFACE
                "${componentSourceFile}"
            )

            target_include_directories(
                hal.${mcu_family_name}.${mcu_subfamily_name}.${component}
                INTERFACE
                "${halIncludeDirectory}"
            )

            list(APPEND halSourceFiles "${componentSourceFile}")
            set(hal_${component}_FOUND TRUE)
        else()
            message(FATAL_ERROR "The requested component: ${component} has not been found in the library!")
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set(hal_${hal_module}_FOUND TRUE)
endforeach()

find_package_handle_standard_args(
    hal
    REQUIRED_VARS halIncludeDirectory halSourceFiles
    FOUND_VAR hal_FOUND
    HANDLE_COMPONENTS
)
```

*CMakeLists.txt in the root directory*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
message(STATUS "CMake Generator is set to ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")

include(FetchContent)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/arm-none-eabi-gcc.cmake)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

message(STATUS "Using toolchain file: ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}.")
message(STATUS "CMake module path: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}.")
if($<CONFIG:Release>)
    message(STATUS "Build type: Release")
else()
    message(STATUS "Build type: Debug")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

project(powerlink-fw)
enable_language(C CXX ASM)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR TRUE)

find_package(cmsis COMPONENTS stm32.g4-v1.2.1)
find_package(hal COMPONENTS stm32.g4-v1.2.1 cortex gpio rcc rcc_ex tim tim_ex pwr pwr_ex exti uart uart_ex dma dma_ex flash flash_ex flash_ramfunc REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES
    core/Src/main.c
    core/Src/stm32g4xx_it.c
    core/Src/stm32g4xx_hal_msp.c
    core/Src/system_stm32g4xx.c
    startup_stm32g474xx.s
)

set(EXECUTABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE}
    hal.stm32.g4
    hal.stm32.g4.rcc
    hal.stm32.g4.gpio
    hal.stm32.g4.cortex
    hal.stm32.g4.uart
    hal.stm32.g4.uart_ex
    hal.stm32.g4.dma
    hal.stm32.g4.dma_ex
    hal.stm32.g4.cortex
    hal.stm32.g4.flash
    hal.stm32.g4.flash_ex
    hal.stm32.g4.flash_ramfunc
    hal.stm32.g4.exti
    hal.stm32.g4.pwr_ex
    hal.stm32.g4.pwr
    hal.stm32.g4.tim
    hal.stm32.g4.tim_ex
    hal.stm32.g4.rcc_ex
    cmsis.stm32.g4
)

target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER
    -DSTM32G474xx
)

target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    core
    core/Inc
    freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/include
    freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F
)

target_compile_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mthumb
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard

    -fdata-sections
    -ffunction-sections

    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/W4 /WX>
    $<$<NOT:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>:-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror>

    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:-Og -g>
)

target_link_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    -T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32G474RETx_FLASH.ld
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mthumb
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard
    -specs=nano.specs
    -lc
    -lm
    -lnosys
    -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map,--cref
    -Wl,--print-memory-usage
    -Wl,--gc-sections
)

# Print image size once build is done
add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-size ${EXECUTABLE}
)

# Create .bin and .hex files
add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex ${EXECUTABLE} ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary ${EXECUTABLE} ${PROJECT_NAME}.bin
)
```

Now I'm trying to create a simple module in a *core* directory and link it in the main *CMakeLists.txt*.

Comment: Can you post your `CMakeLists.txt` (the one that uses FetchContent to get cmsis-src)? Do you call `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` after you declare it?

Comment: You have some mess with the **library** type - IMPORTED / INTERFACE / ALIAS / ... - and with the **linkage** type - PUBLIC / PRIVATE / INTERFACE. The library target created with `add_library(my_lib INTERFACE)` could represent header-only library. But **linkage** with the library is performed with `target_link_libraries(my_other_lib <linkage-type> my_lib)`. A linkage type do NOT depend on the library type. If implementation and public headers of `my_other_lib` use `my_lib`, then use PUBLIC linkage.

Comment: @icebp Updated with all cmake files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  I think I don't understand concept of library type. I thought that if library is of type INTERFACE or PUBLIC, its API is available to other libraries. If this is not the case and it's linkage type which sets such configuration, what is a library type?

Comment: Roughly, the library type affects on the existence of the single **library file** (`.a`, `.so`, etc,) and how this file is obtained. For "normal" library its library file is created during the building process. For the IMPORTED library its library file is already existed. INTERFACE library has no library file. As for ALIAS library, it is a "read-only" wraper around some other library target.

Comment: I'm fetching repository with HAL and CMSIS in find module. I wonder if INTERFACE and IMPORTED types are the correct used here. CMSIS is header only so I think there's no other option than INTERFACE.
Another question, when developing own module for sources directory, as indicated above at the beginning. How should I create library in that sub-CMakeLists.txt? There's a header file which is included in the HAL files (that's not by design...). I'm trying add target_include_directories for that source lib with PUBLIC type but even with that HAL files can't find header file from sources directory.

Comment: Like `INTERFACE` type, `INTERFACE IMPORTED` library type is also suitable for header-only libraries. I don't know about the 3d-party project you use as HAL, but I find strange using **both** INTERFACE/IMPORTED library targets and `FetchContent`. Does this HAL project contain `CMakeLists.txt` file? If yes, then this file usually creates its own library targets. Probably you could use these targets in your project, so no reason to define additional targets. If HAL project doesn't have `CMakeLists.txt`, then `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` cannot be used for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, MCU vendor doesn't provide HAL with CMakeLists.txt so I need to process it on my own. I based above scripts on https://github.com/ObKo/stm32-cmake. Here, the author uses FetchContent_MakeAvailable and then creates a lot of single-file libraries just to make HAL easily available from the main CMakeLists.txt.